# Cannot connect to secured JAXRS endpoint (via CXF via Spring)

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs

I try to implement one JAXRS endpoint with https protocol. I followed the instructions of http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html#SecureJAX-RSServices-Configuringendpoints here.
I have declared a `jaxrs:server` endpoint in my XML file which depends on the `httpj:engine-factory`.

A log file tells me that my service is started and that it is running, but if I try to connect to it, the Firefox web browser tells me "Error: Data Transfer Interrupted" (German: "Fehler: Datenübertragung unterbrochen").  The web service (or JAXRS or CXF) doesn't throw an error message. Opera just says that it cannot connect to the server. Wireshark tells me that the client tries to reconnect to the server a few times and then the client (web browser) seems to give up.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<httpj:engine-factory id="httpsSettings" bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="8545">
        <httpj:tlsServerParameters>
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="...">
                <sec:keyStore type="PKCS12" password="..." file="..."/>
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="..." file="..."/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="false"/>
        </httpj:tlsServerParameters>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>

<jaxrs:server id="cdmiSSLService" address="https://localhost:8545/"
              depends-on="httpsSettings" beanNames="...">
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="..."/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="..."/>
        ...
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="..."/>
        ...
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I should add that I had only one JAXRS endpoint configured at this time, and if I change the JAXRS endpoint configuration to http protocol, everything works fine and I can connect to the web service without any problems.

Can someone please help me what I can do here? I know that isn't much information, but it doesn't give me more information at the moment. Please bear with me, it's the first time that I implement it in that way. I'm a beginner here. It's a Maven multi-module project which uses the Spring Framework. The configuration needs to be via `jaxrs:server`.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found Apache CXF's example which shall work. Maybe it will help me with my problem. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic_https/

Comment: The Apache CXF example works, it will help me to find a solution for my problem. I think it is a certificate problem. I think it will have to do with this fact: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic_https/src/main/config/KeyREADME.txt << The example asked me now if I want to trust the website, that's already very good.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Please don't answer anymore. It helped me to test the with the jks files http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic_https/src/main/config/ and the configuration of http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic_https/src/main/resources/ServerConfig.xml.